# Cadastrar dados no db pelo php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando cadastrar dados no banco de dados pelo php, mas ele não cadastra em utf8, mas quando eu cadastro direto no banco ele cadastra em uf8.

```
<?php
   include("conecta.php");
   function insereUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email) {
      $query = "insert into usuarios (nome, email) values ('{$nome}', '{$email}')";
      return mysqli_query($conexao, $query); 
   }
```

Comment: Poste seu código! Assim fica difícil identifica o erro.

Comment: <?php
include("conecta.php");

function insereUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email) {
 $query = "insert into usuarios (nome, email) values ('{$nome}', '{$email}')";
 return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}

Comment: O seu problema é parecido com esse? --> [Lidando com UTF8 com o PHP e MySQL](http://phpbrasil.com/artigo/11qDFvxJBUXI/lidando-com-utf-8-com-o-php-e-mysql) Explique melhor o problema, se possível, adapte sua pergunta com exemplos! >>[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: tente utilizar ```mysqli_set_charset($conexao, "utf8")```. Documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Deu certo aqui muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria interessante ter acesso ao seu arquivo **conecta.php** para poder prestar um auxilio mais adequado, entretanto, acredito que seu problema possa ser resolvido ao utilizar:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conexao, "utf8")
```

Essa instrução seria colocada dentro do seu **conecta.php** e iria receber o resource de conexão como primeiro parâmetro, já o segundo parâmetro será o seu charset, neste caso **utf8**. Exemplo:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'test');
mysqli_set_charset($conexao, "utf8")
```

Funciona com: (PHP 5 >= 5.0.5, PHP 7)

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: <?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cantina");

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Deu certo aqui muito obrigado.

Comment: Sempre as ordens! Não é escopo deste tópico, porém, te recomendaria usar PDO, acho que além de mais seguro pode acabar sendo mais prático.

Comment: O senhor me recomenda algum livro ou tutorial na net, porque estou aprendendo ainda muita coisa. E obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Para não alongarmos este tópico com assuntos diferentes, entre em contato comigo para conversarmos. Meus dados de contato estão públicos no meu perfil.